# How do I return a list of tuples with each unique string and its count given a list of strings?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Not sure where to start...
item() gives a dictionary and I don't want that.

I would say I need to loop through the list....

Please someone give me some hints so I can get started!

EDIT:

```
count_of_names(names)

    counts_of_names(['John', John', 'Catherine', 'John', 'Christopher', 'Catherine']'
```

output:

```
[('Catherine', 2), ('Christopher', 1), ('John', 3)]
```

Comment: sample input and desired output please

Comment: count_of_names(names) would be the function name...so if    counts_of_names(['John', John', 'Catherine', 'John', 'Christopher', 'Catherine']' the output would be '[('Catherine', 2), ('Christopher', 1), ('John', 3)]

Answer (score 0):

You may use [`collections.Counter()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) to achieve this. Example:

```
>>> x = [1,2,3,4,1,1,2,3]
>>> my_list = Counter(x).items()
>>> my_list
[(1, 3), (2, 2), (3, 2), (4, 1)]

# In order to sort the list base based on value of tuple at index `1` and then index `0`
>>> sorted(my_list, key=lambda x: (x[1], x[0]))
[(4, 1), (2, 2), (3, 2), (1, 3)]
```

Comment: OK, is there any other way to do this without using Counter()?

Comment: To be Frank, there are `N` number of ways and where `N` is infinite. It depends on what you desire

Comment: Well, I prefer with if statements and loops. That's what I've really learned so far.

Comment: Hey sorry, but what if I have two unique strings with the same number of counts and I was trying to order it by count? How would I order them by count and then if there is a tie, order them by alphabet?

Comment: @RandomStuff: Updated the answer with the logic of sort. Also, check the answer mentioned by @zhillang. It is same as what you demanded i.e using `for` and `if`

Answer (score 0):

This is a hard way to do it:

```
x = [1,3,2,5,6,6,3,2]
x_tuple = []

y = set(x)

for i in y:
    x_tuple.append((i,x.count(i)))

print(x_tuple)
```

Comment: Ahhhhhhhhhhhhhhh. So I create an empty tuple and append everything into it....Sorry, but what does set do?

Comment: The `set` is an unordered collection with no duplicate elements. You can read it here: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#sets

Comment: Ah ok. I don't think I need to remove duplicates though, so I shouldn't use it then?

Comment: Terminology point: you don't "create an empty tuple and append everything into it," because in Python tuples are immutable (once you create it, you can't change it -- in particular, you can't append to it). `x_tuple` here is a *list* of *tuples*.

Comment: Your questions said `each unique string and its count`. So i'm use `set` to get unique elements , then loop the unique elements and count everyone

Comment: This technique works, but it is slower than necessary. Each call of `x.count(i)` walks all the way down the `x` list, counting occurrences of i. If there are k unique values, the algorithm looks at each element k times. The algorithm using a dict looks at each element of x only once. @RandomStuff, are you told what the universe of values in x is? If you know that the strings are just "floo", "floom", and "fleem", you can write a loop with an if-elif-elif-else statement that counts the occurrences of the known strings. If the universe of values is large, this idea is ridiculous, of course.

Comment: Oh, no. The strings in the list will be names but they will be random, I believe.

Comment: @zhiliang wang, thank you so much with this answer!  How did you come up with putting extra parenthesis for the two arguments for append since it only takes one argument?

Comment: Are you ask me for that: `x_tuple.append((i,x.count(i)))` ? There are two arguments like i and x.count(i), but set them to be tuple like one argument for list and append it.

Answer (score 0):

Use `set` and list comprehension:

```
def counts_of_names(names):
    return [(name, names.count(name)) for name in set(names)]
```

Comment: Wait how does that work again? I'm not good with so much code on one line :(

Comment: `set(names)` is to get the unique names in list `names`.  `names.count(name)` is to count the occurrence of `name` in list `names`.  Use list comprehension to go through the unique names and return the required tuples `(name, count)`.

Comment: Ahhhh I see. If I were to write this code, I would have the for loop, and then everything else....one line code just confuses me.